# Role base authentication and redirecting request on different pages

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to achieve spring security role based authentication and redirect the user on different pages based on their role. If the user in admin redirect them to admin/index.html and if user is developer redirect them to developer/index.html.

For that I tried below code. I am not facing any exception, but not sure where is the problem. Any help is appreciated !

WebContent/admin/index.html

```
This is admin landing page
```

WebContent/developer/index.html

```
This is developer landing page
```

pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.provm</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-vm-pro</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>aws-vm-pro</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
        <artifactId>javamelody-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.60.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.6.v20130930</version>
            <configuration>
                <webAppSourceDirectory>WebContent</webAppSourceDirectory>
                <httpConnector>
                    <port>8088</port>
                    <host>localhost</host>
                </httpConnector>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java

```
package com.my.app;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(MvcConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class);
    }

}
```

MvcConfig.java

```
package com.my.app;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.my.app")
public class MvcConfig {

    @Bean
    public CustomSuccessHandler getCustomSuccessHandler() {
        return new CustomSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyUserDetailsService getMyUserDetailsService() {
        return new MyUserDetailsService();
    }

}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
package com.my.app;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomSuccessHandler customSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "DEVELOPER").antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .hasRole("ADMIN").antMatchers("/developer/**").hasRole("DEVELOPER").and().formLogin()
                .successHandler(customSuccessHandler).and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

CustomSuccessHandler.java

```
package com.my.app;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.RedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException {
        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);
        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            System.out.println("Can't redirect");
            return;
        }
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }

    protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
        String url = "";
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (GrantedAuthority a : authorities) {
            roles.add(a.getAuthority());
        }
        if (isAdmin(roles)) {
            url = "/admin/index.html";
        } else if (isDeveloper(roles)) {
            url = "/developer/index.html";
        }
        return url;
    }

    private boolean isAdmin(List<String> roles) {
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isDeveloper(List<String> roles) {
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_DEVELOPER")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setRedirectStrategy(RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy) {
        this.redirectStrategy = redirectStrategy;
    }

    protected RedirectStrategy getRedirectStrategy() {
        return redirectStrategy;
    }

}
```

MyUserDetailsService.java

```
package com.my.app;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        String password = null;
        String[] authorities = new String[1];
        String admin = "admin";
        String developer = "developer";
        if (username.equals(admin)) {
            password = "admin";
            authorities[0] = "ADMIN";
        }
        if (username.equals(developer)) {
            password = "developer";
            authorities[1] = "DEVELOPER";
        }
        System.out.println(username + "=" + password + "=" + authorities);
        return new MyUserDetails(username, password, authorities);
    }

}
```

MyUserDetails.java

```
package com.my.app;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities;

    public MyUserDetails(String username, String password, String[] authorities) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.grantedAuthorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(authorities);
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem once that I solved with two security configs and different ant matcher rules for each one. Try to break the problem down into smaller pieces. Isolate the admin and once that works, add developer. Basically use 2 web security config classes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. There was two problem:

```
1. While adding String [] authorities, I should have added authorities[0] instead of authorities[1].
2. In case of admin: authorities[0] = "ROLE_ADMIN", In case of developer authorities[0] = "ROLE_DEVELOPER".
```